# Can these two words 'While' and 'though' be used in the same sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

This is a paragraph describing a computer security software, in order to help you understand more of the context.

> Panda protects its Registry entries against illicit modification, so I
>   couldn't just set "firewall=disabled" in the Registry. I also couldn't
>   terminate its processes using Task Manager. However, a somewhat
>   complex series of actions allowed me to disable its essential
>   services. My Panda contact indicated that it is designed to recover in
>   this situation, but I didn't see that happen. **While** a malware
>   coder could write code to disable protection in this way, **though**
>   it would be a complex task.
>
> Source: http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2429594,00.asp

The last sentence contains both words 'while' and 'though'. Is the word 'though' necessary in this case? Will the sentence sound natural to native speakers if I keep only one of these word (either 'while' or 'though')? Could you give me more examples of using both these words in the same sentence?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but the writer is using "while" in the sense that he should be using "however". My guess is that he was looking for another word to use because "however" was previously used in the same paragraph. Using "while" in this context is definitely non-standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative reading would say that the editor missed a required comma:

> While a malware coder could write code to disable protection in this way, though[**,**] it would be a complex task.

The use of "though" in that fashion is equivalent to "however", so the sentence could be re-written as

> However, while a malware coder could write code to disable protection in this way, it would be a complex task.

(Which means that code-based protection disablement is possible, but it's probably not worth the effort.)

But as @Johnathan Garber points out in a comment, there was already a sentence starting with "However" very close to this one; so the author probably wanted to avoid the repetition.  Thus he went with the alternative structure, and then the comma somehow got dropped.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need both "while" and "though" in that final sentence; in fact, you must choose only one. The sentence doesn't make sense with both of them.

You could choose either one:

- While a malware coder could write code to disable protection in this way, it would be a complex task.
- A malware coder could write code to disable protection in this way, though it would be a complex task.

Both of those sentences make sense and express the same meaning. You could also replace "though" with "but": "A malware coder could write code in this way, but it would be a complex task."